# gganimate does not present points and paths in the correct order

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have the data below and would like to draw an animated ggplot revealing points and paths one by one. For that, I have the variables `from_axp` for the x position, `from_ayp` for the y position and `seq` for the sequence order (the data frame is in correct order, though). Following code from [this](https://goodekat.github.io/presentations/2019-isugg-gganimate-spooky/slides.html#34) slide, I tried running the code below.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = from_axp, y = from_ayp))+
  geom_path()+
  geom_point(aes(group = seq))+
  transition_reveal(along = seq)
```

However, some paths are missing and the points are not revealed in order. The expected output at the end of the animation should look like the static version and the animation should just reveal a single path at a time, but all of them.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = from_axp, y = from_ayp, color = seq))+
  geom_path()+
  geom_text(aes(label = seq), size = 3)
```

Upon closer inspection, I saw that the demo on the slide has the same problem. What is the correct approach to do this?

```
test <- structure(list(from_axp = c(156.3, 140.2, 149, 103.3, 74.8, 164.5, 
186.8, 243.2, 280.3, 130.9, 81, 77.9, 75.2, 152.1, 125.8, 224.6, 
290.1, 310, 307.4, 354.8, 424.5, 378.2, 449.3, 474.2, 444.8, 
421.9, 336.7, 315.7, 452.3, 574.1, 697.3, 581.6, 273.5, 312.7, 
181.7, 714.1, 655.9, 709.3, 843.4, 818.9, 731.9, 706.1, 626.4, 
659.9, 578.4, 725.1, 829.3, 812.9, 834.3, 864.6, 823.9, 844.7, 
916.4, 988.6, 1072.2, 1114.7, 1115.6, 1132.1, 1040, 1007.8, 1102.1, 
1134.4, 1128.7, 1073.1, 1114.2, 1088.6, 1220.5, 1259.9, 1263.5, 
1314.4, 1316.2, 1239.5, 1226.8, 1150, 1080, 1275.2, 1258.4, 1267.7, 
1276.9, 1302.7, 1333.5, 1251.1, 1258.6, 1257.8, 1272.2, 1310.6, 
1411.9, 1466.3, 1397.5, 1327.6, 1340.7, 1443.8, 1495.8, 1328.1, 
1276.2, 1303.6, 1225.7, 1277.5, 1130.6, 1137.4, 1308.9, 1308.8, 
1442.5, 1387.7, 1417.3, 1448.4, 1557.2, 1638.8, 1702.8, 1673.9, 
1731.3, 1731.8, 1715.2, 1697.7, 1717.1, 1714, 1728.8, 1788.4, 
1746.6, 1704.6, 1684.1, 1603.2, 1670, 1658.3, 1715.8, 1798.6, 
1721.6, 1746.3, 1728.4, 1699.1, 1670.7, 1703, 1783.1, 1818.2, 
1780.4, 1717.2, 1652.8, 1530.1, 1558.5, 1590.3, 1492.9, 1449.8, 
1562.5, 1455.2, 1437.3, 1331.6, 1394.2, 1289.4, 1138.4, 1022.4, 
1045.7, 1083.5, 1137.5, 1188.7, 1202.7, 1290.2, 1108.9, 1027.5, 
1133.5, 984.4, 1013.7, 976.6, 987.5, 998.2, 918.2, 1054.9, 1128.9, 
1004, 1015, 986.3, 1047.1, 1077.6, 886.8, 906.3, 837.6, 794, 
755.7, 852.4, 833.1, 780.3, 686.3, 594, 765.7, 815.4, 892.2, 
562.8, 533.2, 370.7, 398, 427.7, 449, 657.1, 601.2, 567.8, 613.3, 
592.7, 565.5, 544.6, 646.5, 681.6, 659.5, 566.2, 544.1, 593.8, 
666.3, 583.9, 544.1, 447.6, 447.1, 379.8, 359.8, 400, 352.8, 
390.6, 370.4, 442.2, 391.1, 146.9, 219.3, 244.1, 171.6, 175.3, 
114.5, 231.8, 225.4, 171.5, 168.4, 139.3, 386, 338.1, 435.3, 
114, 94.7, 166.1, 233.5, 238.3, 168, 144.5, 229.9, 182.9, 149.1, 
207.9, 113.8, 264.1, 258.7, 281.7, 248.6, 168, 179.2, 268.6, 
197.8, 232.5, 243, 258.2, 306.8, 143.5, 350.3, 384.1, 279.7, 
349.1, 374.6, 446.8, 437.6, 505.4, 600, 521.5, 521.9, 588.6, 
631.8, 672.1, 571.6, 589.3, 764.1, 795.9, 826.6, 835.1, 839.9, 
877.1, 874, 806.8, 815.8, 883.6, 936.1, 995, 1012.6, 1142.2, 
1028.9, 1102.7, 1085.9, 1133.8, 1124.3, 1129.2, 1164, 1141.6, 
1240, 1285.6, 1241, 1240.9, 1378.2, 1426.3, 1404.5, 1277.7, 1396.6, 
1397.3, 1403.4, 1473.2, 1498.2, 1447, 1473.8, 1643, 1668.5, 1669.8, 
1670.6, 1622.9, 1677.6, 1754.3, 1712.1, 1738.6, 1681.8, 1437.2, 
1407.6, 1393.8, 1617.5, 1666.1, 1786.2, 1745.3, 1380.1, 1384.2, 
1485.8, 1559.2, 1615.7, 1505.2, 1548.8, 1426.4, 1373.1, 1401, 
1736.1, 1755, 1668.9, 1652.2, 1421.9, 1403.4, 1109.5, 1181.7, 
1194.5, 1078.4, 800.9, 840.4, 840.9, 594.1, 625.6, 852.5, 512.5, 
520.8, 237.1, 311.6, 163.4, 122.9, 130.2, 148.9, 122.4, 97.1, 
103.9, 323, 390.7, 453.9, 663.4, 689.8, 312.1, 366.9, 506.7, 
132.7, 601.7, 566.9, 552.8, 521.7, 827.1, 814.3, 928.8, 895.2, 
1101.4, 1207.9, 1092.1, 1520.3, 1503.8, 1430.5, 1489.5, 1759.5, 
1738.1, 1624.9, 1562.6, 1441.8, 1432.6, 1460.4, 1439.9, 1369.9, 
1076.9, 1148.7, 1028.5, 1448.3, 1403.1, 1667, 1729.3, 1753.9, 
1610.1, 1617.7, 1758.3, 1292.4, 1378.3, 1392.7, 1147.1, 1461.7, 
1420.9, 1625.6, 1663.3, 1699.7, 1744.9, 1719.9, 1685.5, 1717.4, 
1627.9, 1718.1), from_ayp = c(518.5, 538.5, 501.2, 461.8, 402.8, 
509.2, 494.3, 531.5, 476.9, 517.4, 520.5, 408.3, 389, 344.2, 
342.3, 402.4, 413.9, 467.3, 435.6, 483.2, 521.2, 520.2, 490.4, 
456.3, 384.8, 355.2, 426.9, 467, 405.2, 466.7, 531.9, 666.7, 
734.9, 731.2, 720.8, 488.5, 541.9, 539.2, 496.3, 491.1, 544.8, 
527.9, 429.3, 427.9, 353.1, 348.4, 449.6, 490.9, 500.1, 534.5, 
409.2, 345.6, 324.6, 483.3, 523.8, 532.9, 379.6, 380.7, 290.4, 
260.1, 407, 392, 416.5, 451.1, 404.9, 418.7, 455.1, 526.9, 569.7, 
405.5, 415.9, 544.4, 593.8, 617.4, 616.2, 608.4, 470.4, 502.7, 
448.5, 398.2, 422.3, 544, 571.6, 356.8, 372.2, 394.7, 499.2, 
527.2, 392.6, 379.5, 424.4, 432.9, 417.7, 402.3, 420.1, 399.7, 
397.8, 428, 424.6, 379.8, 423.1, 399.9, 506.7, 454.9, 422.1, 
393.4, 442.4, 442.2, 361.3, 504.4, 508.5, 441.8, 453.2, 483.8, 
482, 403.6, 367.7, 402.5, 377.4, 389.5, 479.7, 428.8, 238.2, 
201.6, 151.9, 82.2, 23.3, 20.5999999999999, 207, 238.8, 243, 
272.4, 265.3, 99.2, 134.6, 150.8, 103.6, 159.4, 83.8, 49.8, 262, 
259.1, 260.4, 92.8, 50.8, 106.6, 57.3, 183, 235.9, 273.7, 170.4, 
158.2, 108.1, 92.7, 261.7, 185.8, 274.2, 278.7, 280, 288.9, 292.6, 
347.5, 287.1, 427.4, 425.3, 327.7, 406.6, 279, 283.3, 151.1, 
164.8, 148.6, 321.7, 302.5, 175.5, 119.4, 125.7, 285, 280.9, 
281.8, 190.3, 154.8, 118.5, 101.1, 121.4, 190.4, 266.7, 227.8, 
206.7, 140.2, 113.7, 265.8, 261.4, 309.7, 273.8, 209.6, 185.2, 
119.1, 119.9, 214.3, 194.4, 202.5, 165.3, 157.9, 123.2, 107, 
111.6, 185.2, 138.5, 324.7, 271.9, 286, 249.3, 210, 111.7, 143.7, 
265.9, 313.9, 307.1, 305, 207.9, 365.2, 426.8, 401.7, 475.8, 
228.3, 172, 111.7, 387, 475.5, 530.3, 444.9, 415.7, 246.6, 257.8, 
298.2, 320.1, 307.5, 147, 170.2, 507.8, 368.6, 400.3, 500, 548.2, 
471.1, 684.7, 722.4, 605.6, 614, 676.7, 665.3, 700.9, 755.1, 
757.7, 728.4, 765.2, 761.6, 747.8, 644.7, 586, 567.2, 579.7, 
678.9, 677.6, 778.5, 658.3, 652.5, 595.8, 761.6, 765, 691.4, 
847.8, 785.7, 808.6, 764.1, 788.2, 766, 673.9, 549.4, 573.2, 
583.6, 667.6, 726.2, 678.9, 785.2, 745.2, 619.8, 632.7, 647.3, 
621.8, 583.4, 577.1, 637.2, 654.4, 630, 566.7, 712.4, 719.4, 
714.1, 717.9, 573.8, 704.6, 709.1, 597.9, 715.4, 727.9, 604.9, 
573.7, 762.7, 751.7, 751.9, 561.2, 575.2, 563.5, 580.1, 711.4, 
712.3, 753.6, 684.3, 680.6, 697.6, 676.8, 670.3, 891.5, 881.6, 
701.9, 716.2, 876.2, 906, 909.3, 894.2, 911.2, 866.3, 930.2, 
936.7, 884.4, 887.1, 669.3, 733.7, 710, 718.4, 811, 819.7, 852.4, 
942.8, 815.5, 830.8, 841.6, 868.8, 895.6, 765.2, 733, 764.4, 
726, 745.1, 852.7, 846.6, 909.1, 916.4, 914.5, 800.8, 820.8, 
956.8, 978.2, 995.5, 1013.5, 1011.3, 979.8, 969.4, 937, 973.6, 
837.6, 857.4, 876.3, 883.3, 941.9, 963.5, 1008.5, 1021.2, 1004.9, 
1006.7, 1015.2, 991, 1002.4, 997.5, 1011.5, 860.2, 878.4, 926.9, 
918.1, 869.1, 897.1, 879.2, 817.1, 944.2, 889.8, 793.7, 703.4, 
711.6, 727.9, 861.8, 871.5, 895.6, 840.2, 910, 855.4, 650, 680.6, 
693.7, 772.5, 680.7, 673.9, 742, 726.6, 785.5, 864.3, 853.6, 
796.7, 867.4, 914.5, 893.2), seq = 1:422), row.names = c(NA, 
-422L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you point out something that's missing or not in order? It wasn't obvious to me. I also tried showing every point by increasing the frames and that looked ok too. `animate(ggplot(test, aes(x = from_axp, y = from_ayp))+ geom_path()+ transition_reveal(along = seq), nframes = 422, fps = 25)`

Comment: Thank you, this actually was the issue it seems - I didn't set `nframes` and the default output left out path connections and didn't seem to plot the points in order. The code you sent seems to be working, thank you again!

Comment: The default is 100 frames. At the very least this will necessarily make 4-5 points of your 422 appear with each frame, which could give give the appearance of being out of order even if it worked perfectly. And it sounds like there might be other errors with your setup, but I couldn't reproduce and don't know the cause.

Comment: Actually, the problem still seems to persist. For instance, point 9 is presented some time after point 80 with this code  `(ggplot(test, aes(x = from_axp, y = from_ayp))+
  geom_path()+
  geom_point(aes(group = seq))+
  geom_text(aes(group = seq, label = seq), size = 4, position = position_nudge(x = 15))+
  transition_reveal(along = seq)) %>%
  animate(nframes = 422, fps = 2)`

Comment: Looks ok for me I think (using 4 fps)? https://imgur.com/a/bVoONJi. I am using gganimate 1.0.7

Comment: Yours does look okay, this is what mine looks like @2FPS: https://imgur.com/cJhZH1P I have gganimate 1.0.8

Comment: It seems like this is a version issue. Under 1.0.7, this does not happen, under 1.0.8 it does. Not sure if this should be reported as a bug. Another difference is that in 1.0.7, the end of the line also has a point and the corresponding number, whereas the point and number shows up in the next frame in 1.0.8 (see imgurs above).

Comment: Yes, sounds like a bug. I'd suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues, ideally with a smaller example if you can find one.

Comment: Bug report: https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/486

Comment: Maybe try the dev version of 'gganimate'. Thomas has made lots of bug fixes there recently, including others that look like this.